# How can I make zoomable square table in SFML?

Tags: c++, sfml, tile

How can I make zoomable square table like in the picture below?

[image: Zoomable gif example]

At first, there is no tile in squares.
but when zoom in, tiles are slowly appearing inside squares.

And another question, can I have paint bucket tool and use to fill my tile then store information into array?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2):

In SFML this can be done using a so-called `sf::View`. This allows you to have a world defined and have different and changing views on it, like in your example.

There is a very good introduction to `Views` in `SFML` [here](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/graphics-view.php).